# MonoDroid: Debugger timeout

Tags: xamarin.android

When using MonoDroid 1.0.2, I am unable to get teh debugger to connect:

```
08-12 17:35:27.760: INFO/MonoDroid-Debugger(478): 
Not starting the debugger as the timeout value has been reached; 
current-time: 1313170527  timeout: 1313169442
```

Can the timeout get increased? This is a **HellowWorld** App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need it to be longer?

30 seconds should be enough time for your app to start up and check that flag.

Comment: I'm running it in VS2010, that is running on a Mac in VMWare Fusion. It takes nearly a minute to run.

Comment: No, the timeout cannot be increased.